# Google Container Engine - How should I create two separate L7 load balancers in the same project?

Tags: http, load-balancing, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to have two different clusters in the same Google Container Engine (GKE) project, production and staging. How do I create a separate [L7 load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) for each?

I've tried to create one L7 ingress per cluster, but it seems for the second one it's only partially created and conflicts instead with the other one. Specifically, the backend services of the second LB are unhealthy and point to the instance group belonging to the first LB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md) with the gclb ingress controller, which is currently in beta:

> [UIDs](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md#running-multiple-loadbalanced-clusters-in-the-same-gce-project): If you're creating multiple clusters that will use Ingress within a single GCE project, you must assign a UID to GLBC so it doesn't stomp on resources from another cluster.